# Why there is no general equation to denote polygons?

Tags: geometry

We have algebraic equations for conic sections, like circle, ellipses and parabolas, but why there is no such result for polygons like triangle or square or hexagon? Is it impossible to represent polygons as algebraic identities?

Comment: One way of trying to carry this out is described in my 19 August 2014 math-teach post [How to obtain an equation of a polygon](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=9567096) at Math Forum, and in [this follow-up post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=9568881) I give 10 literature references for this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For  the square with  corners $(1,0)$,  $(0,1)$, $(-1,0)$, and $(0,-1)$, we have the equation $|x|+|y|=1$. From this we can get the general equation of a square.  If one does not want to use absolute values, we can replace $|w|$ by $\sqrt{w^2}$.

One can with some effort get  equations for regular $n$-gons. They are not particularly useful.